# Ruby On Rails - Rspec issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, railstutorial.org

Trying to run

```
$ bundle exec rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb
```

from chapter 3.2.1 of [this tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages?version=4.0#sec-static_pages)

However I'm getting the following error before the test can even run:

```
/Users/alexrahr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `load': cannot load such file -- /Users/alexrahr/Apps/ruby.railstutorial.org/rails_projects/sample_app/app/spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb (LoadError)
from /Users/alexrahr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `block in load_spec_files'
from /Users/alexrahr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `each'
from /Users/alexrahr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `load_spec_files'
from /Users/alexrahr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
from /Users/alexrahr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run'
from /Users/alexrahr/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'
```

Any ideas what it might be? I'm guessing it's that I don't have the RSpec gem installed?

Comment: FYI just checked and I do have Rspec in gem file 

`group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.8'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'
end

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'
  gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
end`

Comment: Worked it out - was just trying to run the command from the wrong folder...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the spec/ directory nest is based on the type of spec:

- for model specs: spec/models/user_spec.rb
- for controller specs: spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb

Also make sure you ran the rake rspec:install command after bundle

```
bundle && rake rspec:install
```

The error clearly states that the file you are trying to run is not found in the directory you say it is in.